Trouble calling method on my DAPP on Devnet using Solathon libs
Trying to use Python Solathon library to store a file hash (fake one) onto the blockchain using a DAPP on Devnet.  I think the issue is in how I'm building the instruction (data field in particular) that is causing a return of "errors reported:  Failed to fetch data from RPC endpoint. Error -32601: Method not found"
the DAPP is such:
'''
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::entrypoint::ProgramResult;

declare_id!("BBamUWV9wdHDeyQqNQA5jPxGwKesmzGpWvkxHULNF4sZ");
// declare_id!("Eht9Srm1t6VZaHMqoWdLEhRMfeK3BvXFQLxKgcQeUcmX");

// declare_id!("Fg6PaFzn4k8nFmVSLKsacn7MsHHSu1yKAMkXm3vR45N");

#[program]
pub mod my_solana_program {
    use super::*;
    pub fn store_hash(ctx: Context<StoreHash>, my_hash: String) -> ProgramResult {
        let hash_record = &mut ctx.accounts.hash_record;
        hash_record.value = my_hash;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn get_hash(ctx: Context<GetHash>) -> ProgramResult {
        let hash_record = &ctx.accounts.hash_record;
        msg!("Stored Hash: {}", hash_record.value);
        Ok(())
    }

}

#[account]
pub struct HashRecord {
    pub value: String,
}

#[account]
pub struct GreetingAccount {
    pub counter: u64,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct StoreHash<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 9000)]
    pub hash_record: Account<'info, HashRecord>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct GetHash<'info> {
    pub hash_record: Account<'info, HashRecord>,
}
'''

The python code that tries to make the call is:
'''
from solathon import Client, Transaction, PublicKey, ProgramAccount, Instruction, Keypair

# Initialize Solana client for Devnet
client = Client(BLOCK_CHAIN)

#create a keypair (wallet) from the id.json file (I've imported the 'list' as WALLET_Private_KEY)
wallet_keypair = Keypair.from_private_key(WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY_LIST)

#DAPP address as a PublicKey - DAPP address is imported from OS as DAPP_PUBLIC_KEY
dapp_pubkey = PublicKey(DAPP_PUBLIC_KEY)

# build the data field of instruction - first byte is for function id, then some fake hash data
instruction_data =  b'\x01' + bytes.fromhex('00' * 32)

# Create an instruction to send the data to the DApp
instruction = Instruction(
    keys=[{
        'pubkey': wallet_keypair.public_key,
        'is_signer': True,
        'is_writable': True,
    }],
    program_id=dapp_pubkey,
    data=instruction_data
)

# Create the transaction per https://dev.to/0xbolt/how-to-send-solana-transaction-using-python-1dii
transaction = Transaction(instructions=[instruction], signers=[wallet_keypair])

# Send the transaction
response = client.send_transaction(transaction)
print(f"Transaction Signature: {response}")
'''

Solathon docs are not clear on how to send data to a DAPP.  (https://solathon.vercel.app/)

If you're seeing an error of Failed to fetch data from RPC endpoint. Error -32601: Method not found, it sounds like your Python library version might be old and calling a deprecated RPC function.
Try upgrading to a newer version of Solathon if it exists, or switch to using solana-py https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py

Thank you for the suggestion, but all libraries are up to most recent versions.
I have not found an answer, but I'm still pointed toward error in how the instruction field is constructed, that the instruction isn't being passed to the DAPP correctly.
Frustrated a bit, as there are many examples of interacting with the system application to do a wallet balance check (that works excellently) or even a transfer of lamports, but can't find a singular example of using Solathon to interact with a multi-functional DAPP

Even if the libraries are all up to the most recent versions, their code might still be out of date. Looking at the solathon source code, their get_recent_blockhash function at https://github.com/GitBolt/solathon/blob/5f82e65336a74226c5b66b607a605ca9a78f4dcf/solathon/client.py#L431 is using a deprecated RPC method that has been removed https://solana.com/docs/rpc/deprecated/getrecentblockhash -- try a different library or send a PR to them to use newer endpoints

hey @WilliamDockery, i built solathon and don't maintain it anymore.
just saw this thread and i've pushed the fix to it. you may reinstall the package and it should be fine.
however, i would recommend for more usecases, you may switch to solana.py as its more actively maintained.

Jon C  thank you!  I had not thought of it that way.  I'm way too trusting of libraries.  Deeply Appreciated!  (as you can see Syed basically confirmed you were right, and I didn't understand fully)

@SyedAabisAkhtar  Syed, Thank you for confirming the issues Jon pointed out.  TY for updating the library, although I think I'll take your advice and try solana.py again.  I had a lot of issue with its integration with solders.  (never got it working).   This is why I sought out an alternative.  Your Solathon library was a great idea.  I wish it was maintained,   Thank you for the reply!
